How to marshal all the various ways of installing things under Linux?
~or:~  The Linux equivalent of UniGetUI (née WinGetUI)?
In the world of Linux, there are various ways to install stuff:  "on bare metal" (apt, rpm. etc.), Docker containers, Snaps, Flatpaks, and so on.  Is there a utility that wrangles all these together nicely so I can decide which of these to choose for a given thing I want to install, based on what's available which way (and, ideally, how advisable each choice is)?

Sorry, the question is too wide.

This is a case with many challenges. Let me try to point to some of them:

you may have one package/functionality in more than one type of repo. Which one you will use?
packages from different repos can use different user configuration directories
some packages may use much more space. For example snap packages "carry" all the dependencies so you have more used space
update for vulnerabilities may be a challenge because different repos have different schedule to update packages. Moreover snap type repos will update the things for one package, not entire OS
dependencies trees between distributions is different so will be VERY hard to keep things consistent
formats of different packages may be not compatible with distribution. So it may be need of convert which is always challenge.
companies which provide support/subscription will not be able to provide consistent system because of the sources outside their control.
one file may be part of different packages (from different sources). What to do with existing file?

and so on...
